# Count total hours and minutes in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, count

I am calculating the work hours of an employee between two dates. The input is a date interval. The process is going through in a foreach loop. The issue is that when the time calculation exceeds from 24 hours, it shows a strange behavior. I want a exact calculation like 35:55 etc. You can see the screen shot. Black highlighted time calculation is not correct. Expected result is exact calculation of the 'Hours Worked'.
[image: You can see the screen shot. Black highlighted time calculation is not correct.]

```
$hoursWorked      = '00:00';

foreach ($distinctDates as $dist){
 $att = $ci->Attendance_Model->filter_att_date_for_report($dist->date, $emp->user_id);

    $totalHours += TotalWorkHoursPerDay;
    // working hours after subtracting brb time
    $work_hours = gmdate("H:i", strtotime($att->working_hours) - strtotime($att->brbtime));


     $WorkHrsSecs = strtotime($work_hours)-strtotime("00:00");
     $hoursWorked = date("H:i",strtotime($hoursWorked)+$WorkHrsSecs);
 }
```

Please help me improve this code or suggest me another solution for achieving the desired result. I am working in Codeigniter. Thanks.

Comment: Commenting your code would be more helpfull for as to understand your logique.

Comment: Please show us the input data and expected results. We also don't know which parts of your code do what, or what debugging you've done. Don't make us do all the work - help us to help you and explain what's currently going on. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question and cleaned the garbage code. Hope so it is now understandable.

Comment: `date("H:i", ...)` isn't practical for something like > 24h (date formats a datetime, hence it only displays up until 23:59). You may need to switch to "manual" counting of minutes/hours (one var for minutes, at the end converting into hours/minutes, by dividing/modulo by 60)

Comment: use date_diff function